# Connecting to a SQL DB through PHP on another network

Tags: php, sql, linux

Here is my scenario

- PC with php site and apps connected to 10.1.75.* network
- (A) Database server connected to same 10.1.75.* network
- (B) secondary database connected to 10.198.140.* network

Now my problem, i can pull info from my primary database (A) without hassle, but when i want info from secondary DB (B) i need to log in on (A) via SSH and do mysql -h 10.198.140.*** to get onto that DB

Is it in anyway possible that i can pull info from (B) without being on the same network, basically daisy chain through (A) to (B) to get the info i need and doing this in PHP?

Comment: Only if server B allows direct connections from your server's ip address

Comment: And only if the account on server B allows the connection from PC's IP address.

Comment: Hmmm this is a tough one, ill ask the net admin to allow for connections

Answer (score 0):

Well, easiest would be to gain access through a public IP to server B so you can connect to it directly.

If that's not possible, another option is to set up a slave database on server A that is updated via replication from server B and query it directly on A. However, replication can be a pain to manage and you can't write to it, only read.

You could also set up a proxy on A on a different port to route through to B, though I can't help you there, I'm no sys admin.

I don't really get how A can talk to B but your server can't, that doesn't make any sense, if you can set up the permissions for A to talk to B, you should be able to do the same for your server.